# Using Google Analytics from an Intranet

Tags: google-analytics

We have setup GA from an intranet, however we are not sure if everything is tracked correctly.  We should be getting more unique hits/page views than GA reports.

All of our intranet users gets the same external IP address and we are not sure if this makes GA believe that all the requests are coming from the same user or a limited number of unique users at least.

How does GA determine the uniqueness of a the requests? and is there a way to provide another "unique" key if needed?

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics does not IP adresses for that purpose. It creates an id for every browser where the tracking code is run and stores it in a cookie (on browser that do not allow cookies data will still be sent but will not be grouped into user sessions, however with Universal Analytics you can choose to provide a uuid yourself).

Since you intranet users are presumably authenticated you could use the [user id feature](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id) in Universal Analytics. However this should not be necessary (it was developed to recognize authenticated users across devices, so it might be useful if you users log in to different computers).

But as long as javascript is enabled and allowed to set cookies (and of course there is an internet connection) there should be no problems. IP is used for geolocation only.